# Display a view of geolocation fields with lat lon on a google (or equiv) map

Tags: location

I have a geolocation module installed with a field that geolocates and gives a lat lon value. Then I want to use a view of these values to show them in google maps or equivalent. If there is a quick and dirty solution would be good, otherwise I would spend time coding one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this sandbox module geolocation views with geolocation field module.
http://drupal.org/sandbox/xandeadx/1782036